# PDFTK Output Same Size as Input Regardless of Cat'd Page Count

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I'm running into a weird situation with a particular group of PDFs and not sure where to start. If I burst a 25M, 600 pg file, the output becomes 25M per bursted file. If I do pdftk input.pdf cat 1-100 output out.pdf the size is also 25M (25292kb vs 25524kb for original). Doing page range 1-5 results in a  file size of 25040kb.

Is there a flag that I can add to pdftk to handle this situation? Ghostscript can take a page range from this pdf and make an appropriate size PDF but gs doesn't seem to handle burst as well as requires having every font installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably making the following assumption about PDF: if you have a PDF with file size 3000 KB and 10 pages, then splitting this PDF will result in 30 files with file size 300 KB.

This assumption is wrong. Imagine a 3000 KB document with ten pages and the following objects:

- four font subsets used on every page, each about 50 KB
- ten images that figure on a single page, each about 200 KB (one image per page)
- four images that figure on every page, each about 50 KB
- ten pages with content streams of about 25 KB each
- about 350 KB for objects such as the catalog, the info dictionary, the page tree, the cross-reference table, etc...

A single page will need at least:
- the four font subsets: 4 times 50 KB
- the single image: 1 time 200 KB
- the four images: 4 times 50 KB
- a single content stream: 1 time 50 KB
- a slightly reduced cross-reference table, a slightly reduced page tree, an almost identical catalog, an info dictionary of identical size,... 200 KB

Together that's 850 KB. This means that you end up with 8500 KB (10 times 850 KB) if you split up a 10-page 3000 KB PDF document into 10 separate pages.

My guess is that the shared resources (resources that are used in every page, e.g. fonts) are huge in your PDF. E.g. if someone used a high-resolution image as the background of each page that takes about 25M, then each of your 600 pages will need those 25M.

Note that PdfTk is nothing more than a wrapper around an obsolete version of iText. You may want to try a more recent version of iText to find out if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, that's very insightful and I was having trouble finding that type of information. Any suggestion on how to analyze and possibly drop that information? Ghostscript seems to be capable of carte blanche dropping the info and creating small individual files that are not too much larger in aggregate than the original single file. pdf2ps and then back does as well, but is resource hungry.

Comment: I think gs kind of "prints" the PDF and by doing so reduces the resolution and removes stuff like structure trees, annotations, and so on. Also note that PdfTk is old: it doesn't support the more advanced compression introduced in PDF 1.5. Without seeing the file, it is hard to comment on the actual problem.