# Pdftk burst splitting PDF file generates nearly same size of the parent file

Tags: pdftk

I have a 361 page PDF file and try to split each page into directory. I used burst method of pdftk. However, original file size is 11mb but the generated file sizes are 10mb which makes nearly 4gb when bursting done.

```
pdftk orjFile.pdf burst output %01d.pdf
```

[image: Burst result]

Is there an any solution to this bug ? or You can suggest me another free library to try (i used PdfBox but i gave the same result).

Comment: Maybe the resources (images, fonts) are global, in that case every page will need them. Please share source and one result file for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PDFTK Output Same Size as Input Regardless of Cat'd Page Count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40598770/pdftk-output-same-size-as-input-regardless-of-catd-page-count)